# Python csv dictionary calling from a dictionary to repeat rows in a csv according to dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Hi everyone so I have a question in regards to a issue I am having.

Here is a sample input csv:

```
Alfa,Beta,Charlie,Delta,Echo,Foxtrot,Golf,Hotel,India,Juliett,Kilo
A,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1,G1,H1,I1,J1,
A,B2,C2,D2,E2,F2,G2,H2,I2,J2,1
B,B3,C3,D3,E3,F3,G3,H3,I3,J3,
B,B4,C4,D4,E4,F4,G4,H4,I4,J4,
```

This is a version of a code that i have:

```
import csv

fieldnames_dict = {
    'Alfa': 'Alfa_New',
    'Echo': 'Echo_New',
    'Foxtrot': 'Foxtrot_New_ALL',
    'Hotel': 'Hotel_New',
    'India': 'India_New',
    'Charlie': 'Charlie_New'
}

with open("book1.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore') as csv_in:
    with open("xtest_file.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore') as csv_out:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csv_in, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_out, delimiter=',', quotechar='"',
                                fieldnames=list(fieldnames_dict.values()))
        writer.writeheader()
        for row_in in reader:
            row_out = {new: row_in[old] for old, new in fieldnames_dict.items()}
            writer.writerow(row_out)
```

What this code does, is pretty much rearrange the the columns according to the dictionary.

However I need to repeat some rows of the csv file according to a new dictionary and also rename the value of that column's row.

For example:

```
second_dictionary = {
    'A' : '1ST,2ND,3RD",
    'B' : '4TH',
    }
```

This dictionary will need to be compared with the column "*Alfa*") and when it finds that it has the values of '*A*', it will then repeat that row with the values of '1ST', '2ND' and '3RD'.
If the column "*Alfa*" has the value of '*B*', it will look at the dictionary and replace only once by it self as the 4TH.

What the output should look like:

```
Alfa_New,Echo_New,Foxtrot_New_ALL,Hotel_New,India_New,Charlie_New
1ST,E1,F1,H1,I1,C1
2ND,E1,F1,H1,I1,C1
3RD,E1,F1,H1,I1,C1
1ST,E2,F2,H2,I2,C2
2ND,E2,F2,H2,I2,C2
3RD,E2,F2,H2,I2,C2
4TH,E3,F3,H3,I3,C3
4TH,E4,F4,H4,I4,C4
```

As you can see, since the input file had this row:

```
Alfa,Beta,Charlie,Delta,Echo,Foxtrot,Golf,Hotel,India,Juliett,Kilo
A,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1,G1,H1,I1,J1,
```

With the second dictionary, it will need to replace the 'A' from Alfa and copy it self 3 times but replacing the values from the second dictionary:

```
Alfa_New,Echo_New,Foxtrot_New_ALL,Hotel_New,India_New,Charlie_New
1ST,E1,F1,H1,I1,C1
2ND,E1,F1,H1,I1,C1
3RD,E1,F1,H1,I1,C1
```

What will I need to do for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this could help:

```py
import csv

fieldnames_dict = {
    'Alfa': 'Alfa_New',
    'Echo': 'Echo_New',
    'Foxtrot': 'Foxtrot_New_ALL',
    'Hotel': 'Hotel_New',
    'India': 'India_New',
    'Charlie': 'Charlie_New'
}

second_dictionary = {
    'A': '1ST,2ND,3RD',
    'B': '4TH',
}

with open("book1.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore') as csv_in:
    with open("xtest_file.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore') as csv_out:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csv_in, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_out, delimiter=',', quotechar='"',
                                fieldnames=list(fieldnames_dict.values()))
        writer.writeheader()
        for row_in in reader:
            row_out = {new: row_in[old] for old, new in fieldnames_dict.items()}
            column_name = 'Alfa_New'
            column_key = row_out[column_name]
            if column_key in second_dictionary.keys():
                for item in second_dictionary[column_key].split(','):
                    row_out[column_name] = item
                    writer.writerow(row_out)
            else:
                writer.writerow(row_out)
```